# Changing data type from character to numeric

Tags: r, database, dataframe, struct

I have a data frame called *cds* in excel that consist in several prices over time as follows:
[image]

The main problem is that when I export the data, R treat the prices as characters, so I cannot run time series commands over the data.

[image]

I already try the argument `col_types` in the `read_excel` function, but the problem is that consider the first date column as a number and not date format as it should.

I already try as well the `as.numeric`command, however it shrink the hole data frame into a simple  vector.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `type.convert()`:

```
library(dplyr)

result <- cds %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)

result
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr::mutate` for this:

```
## make some fake data ##
mtcars$mpg = as.character(mtcars$mpg)
mtcars$cyl = as.character(mtcars$cyl)

## the columns we want to convert to numeric
cols = c("mpg", "cyl")

## command to mutate the cols and apply the function as.numeric to them
librar(dplyr)
mtcars %>% mutate(across(all_of(cols), as.numeric))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution that does not need additional packages as it uses just "base **R**" functions:

```r
## create a data example
df <- data.frame(
  id = letters[1:10],
  x = as.character(sample(10, 10)),
  y = as.character(runif(10))
)

## convert columns x and y
cols <- c("x", "y")
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], as.numeric)
```

It works with `lapply` (*list apply*) because a `data.frame` is essentally a list of columns.

As an alternative, we can also use `type.convert` (as suggested by @TarJae) even without **dplyr**:

```r
df <- type.convert(df, as.is=TRUE)
```